# How to split data into train set (and test set) every nrows in R?

Tags: r, split, training-data

I've got a classification problem where I have a huge DATASET containing 308.500 data. I want to split these data into a train set and a test set in order to create a model.

But I want the train data to take, for example, sample for the DATASET every nrows, for example every 1.000 rows, so I know that the train set will be constructed by rows from all the DATASET. Is there a way to do this?

For example I'd like something like this:

```
train = DATASET[take sample every 1000 rows]
```

Comment: have you seen this similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30885047/how-to-non-randomly-sample-every-n-rows-in-dplyr)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `seq` to create indices of rows to subset.

```
train_inds <- seq(1, nrow(DATASET), 1000)
train <- DATASET[train_inds, ]
test <- DATASET[-train_inds, ]
```

Comment: Thanks! And do you know how I take the rest of the data for the test set?